# Find elements which have jquery widgets initialized upon them

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

I am using the [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) widget (although I believe this question can generalize to any jQuery widget). The [API](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API) instructs the user to initialize the the widget using the `fileupload` method, thus:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload();
```

My question is: Without knowing IDs, how can I find `#fileupload` (and any other elements which have had `.fileupload()` called upon them?

Comment: Duke, it looks like you are using the jQuery-File-Upload widget within ajax-loaded content. Could you help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265932/multiple-jquery-plugin-instances-in-ajax-loaded-html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery File Upload uses the jQuery UI widget factory under the hood, and that factory is known to register the widgets instances with the elements they extend using [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Therefore, you can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and write something like:

```
// Restrict ancestor if you can, $("*") is expensive.
var uploadified = $("#yourAncestor *").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("fileupload");
});
```

***Update:*** From jQuery UI 1.9 onwards, [the `data()` key becomes the widget's fully qualified name, with dots replaced by dashes](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changed-naming-convention-for-data-keys). Therefore, the code above becomes:

```
var uploadified = $("#yourAncestor *").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("blueimp-fileupload");
});
```

Using the unqualified name is still supported in 1.9 but is deprecated, and support will be dropped in 1.10.