# Multiple jQuery plugin instances in ajax-loaded html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, blueimp

I am using multiple [Blueimp File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options) plugins in ajax-loaded html :

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
    $( "#details" ).show();
    $('#details div').html(ajax_spinner).load(script.php, "parameters");
});
```

So when you click something class="edit" a new div id="details" is shown (but it **was** in the DOM when document.ready) and script.php returns a form id="upload" (which is **never** visible in "view source", although it *is* there in the page..?

What is the rule/good practice for dealing with html added *after* the document.ready?

So now there is a new element in this "virtual DOM" :

```
<form id="upload" method="post" action="other_script.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div id="drop">
    DROP HERE <small>Image .png or .jpg</small>
    <a class="btn mr_button">Browse</a>
    <input type="file" name="upl" />
  </div>
  <ul id="mr_uploaded_files_ul">
    <!-- The global progress bar -->
    <div id="progress" class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
  </ul>
</form>
```

And when I try to act upon this "invisible" part of the DOM :

```
$('#drop a').click(function(){
    alert('Nope. Nothing');
});
```

Only when I

```
$(document).on('click', '#drop a', function() {
    alert('Ah, this works');
});
```

But I need more than an alert. The whole `$('#upload').fileupload({ ... })` callback suite is not executed, probably because of this DOM "existence" issue. BTW I use this very implementation in other pages, on plain existing DOM, and it works.

How can I act upon those newly-spawned DOM elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a callback function to your `load` call, and then initialize your form.

```
$('#details div').html(ajax_spinner).load(script.php, "parameters", function() {
    $('#upload').fileupload({ ... });
});
```

When you use a jQuery selector, like $('#upload'), those elements have to *already* exist. The upload form doesn't exist until after it's been loaded, so that selector returns empty until after the load finishes.

The reason the alert works

```
$(document).on('click', '#drop a', function() {
    alert('Ah, this works');
});
```

is due to event delegation. Read more here: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Hi, furydevoid. I tried that, and can't get it to return anything after the add: callback... It very much can be the plugin itself... Why can't I even see anything in the FireBug console ? Note that when I do call the plugin from within the callback, nothing changes in the source...

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'return'? It's an async operation, so it won't return anything to outer code. The plugin could be broken, as well --

Comment: Well, if I put a console_log('something'); in the add: callback of the fileupload({ ... }) function, I will see it IF the form is not ajax-loaded. And putting this function in the html load callback does not change this. I so hoped it would.

Comment: I guess, since only event delegation works, my question is now "how can I delegate the whole $('#upload').fileupload({ ... }); function?"

Comment: You can't, you can only catch delegated events. You'll have to initialize the upload plugin *after* the new dom elements have been loaded, if the plugin is functioning correctly. If you can provide a complete example, I can look at it later and help to explain.

Comment: Your answer seem to say that if you use the callback in a .load() function at all, the content returned *will* "exist" (ie be visible in the source). Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes -- the point of the callback in the .load jquery function is that the callback is called after the new content is in the DOM. The source code is just a blueprint for the browser to initialize the DOM. Think of it as a big object in memory that has a lot more to it than the source HTML. Here's a little explanation of it: http://css-tricks.com/dom/

Comment: +1 for that last info. My problem is not solved :( but I learned something big (view source is NOT the DOM) thanks.